# Drawing like "from-to" in bitmap image

Tags: c, bitmap, line

We know the streight line that mspaint can draw into a picture. Since nested loops fill the whole area (x/y) i was wondering whats the way of doing this. Drawing a line from (x0 y0) of the image to desired x/y. Im using this function for finding the x/y pixel of the bmp:

```
dword find (FILE* fp, dword xp, dword yp)
{
    word bpx = (3*8);
    dword offset = (2+sizeof(BMP)+sizeof(DIB));
    dword w = 500;

    dword row = (((bpx * w) * 4) / 32);
    dword pixAddress = (offset) + row * yp + ((xp * bpx) / 8);

    return pixAddress;
}
```

And I've tried with many functions for drawing line from 0x0 to xy, their results are close.. but not entirely.

Comment: You *are* aware that you cannot draw an angled, straight line on a raster bitmap? So how "close" do you need it to be? A small part of your observed deviation may be because you are using integer arithmetic & rounding. Using floating point values will -- well, not *remove* rounding errors, but at least make them way, way smaller.

Comment: What.. i almost succeeded anyway.. There is a way.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code that worked best for you -- if possible, with a sample result image. At least we'll get an idea of what your "close but not entirely" looks like.

Comment: There are a lot of codes that are "close but not entirely" But i guess i will stick with the following: *posting answer*

Answer (score 1):

```
byte color_pattern[] = { 255, 255, 255 };
dword xy_offset[] = {1, 1};

void bmp_lineto(dword endx, dword endy)
{
    int dx = endx - xy_offset[0];
    int dy = endy - xy_offset[1];
    int twody = 2 * dy;
    int twodxdy = 2 * (dy - dx);
    int dp = twody - dx;
    int X, Y, xEnd, yEnd;
    FILE* fp = fopen(convert(FILENAME.text), "rb+");

    if(xy_offset[0] > endx)
    {
        X = endx;
        Y = endy;
        xEnd = xy_offset[0];
    }
    else
    {
        X = xy_offset[0];
        Y = xy_offset[1];
        xEnd = endx;
    }
    while(X < xEnd)
    {
        X = X + 1;
        if(dp < 0)
        {
            dp = dp + twody;
        } else { Y = Y + 1; dp = dp + twodxdy;
        }
    fseek(fp, find(fp, X, Y), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&color_pattern, 1, 3, fp);
    }
}
```

But the result on the bmp from this code is so... uncertain:
`bmp_lineto(200, 230);` The entire image is `x500 : y460`
UPDATED. The y coordinate is same as x. Thats the problem

[image]

Comment: What do you mean - "the result is uncertain"?

Comment: As you can see on the picture. There are two lines drawn instead.. and the coordinates are wrong.

Comment: Updated. The problem is that it draws it with wrong coordinates. In this case from `bmp_lineto(200, 230);` it draws the line on `x200 : y200` It uses the coords of x as a y.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following code - I adapted this from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NX 40
#define NY 20
typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} point;

typedef struct{
  char M[NX][NY];
} bitmap;

void drawLine(point *a, point*b, bitmap *B, FILE* fp, byte *color_pattern) {
  int x0 = a->x, y0 = a->y;
  int x1 = b->x, y1 = b->y;
  int dx = abs(x1-x0), sx = (x0<x1) ? 1 : -1;
  int dy = abs(y1-y0), sy = (y0<y1) ? 1 : -1;
  int err = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2, e2;
  int index;
  while(1){
    // the next three lines put the pixel right in the file:
    index = (y0 * NX + x0)*3;
    fseek(fp, index, SEEK_SET); 
    fwrite(color_pattern, 1, 3, fp);

    B->M[x0][y0]=1;  // for code testing

    if (x0==x1 && y0==y1) break;
    e2 = err;
    if (e2 >-dx) { err -= dy; x0 += sx; }
    if (e2 < dy) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
  }
}

void printLine(bitmap *B){
  int ii, jj;
  for(ii=0; ii<NY; ii++) {
    for(jj=0; jj<NX; jj++) {
      printf("%d", (int)B->M[jj][ii]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  point start = {34,7};
  point end = {14, 17};
  bitmap B;
  byte color[]={255,255,255};

  // initialize map to zero. Want to do same with file I suppose
  int ii, jj;
  for(ii=0; ii<NX; ii++) {
    for(jj=0; jj<NY; jj++) {
      B.M[ii][jj]=0;
    }
  }
  fp = fopen("mypicture.bmp", "wb");

  drawLine(&start, &end, &B, fp, color);
  printLine(&B);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

I think it should be easy to adapt it for your situation. Note I have tried to separate / localize variables a little more - that is usually a good idea; there are still many ways to further improve this code (this is a situation where C++ might be a better language...)

Output of the above:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000001100000
0000000000000000000000000000000110000000
0000000000000000000000000000011000000000
0000000000000000000000000001100000000000
0000000000000000000000000110000000000000
0000000000000000000000011000000000000000
0000000000000000000001100000000000000000
0000000000000000000110000000000000000000
0000000000000000011000000000000000000000
0000000000000001100000000000000000000000
0000000000000010000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Looks like the "right" line to me... even though it's got the X going in the negative direction. That's the advantage of starting with proven code (in this case, Bresenham's algorithm as implemented on Rosettacode).

Comment: I will try it! Note that I can't chooce language nor even compiler. Im doing this on closed sdk-based engine with really ancien C. I know its a torture but..

Comment: I did not test this extensively. I just realized, for example, that it will fail if either `dx<0` or `dy<0`. Will adapt just to cope with those cases... hang on.

Comment: Yeah.. with my shorty function it works only if `x>y` else way .. it will make y  equivalent of x.

Comment: Updated with a function that ought to work for all directions of the line.

Comment: Its.. not working it draws only a single pixel in the output bmp.
I use:
`fseek(fp, find(fp, ii, jj), SEEK_SET); fwrite(&color_pattern, 1, 3, fp);` instead of `  drawLine(&start, &end, &B); printLine(&B);`

Comment: You need to put your `fseek` **inside** the `drawLine` function because that's where all the interesting stuff is happening. But why are you writing to a file instead of memory? With random access that will be really, really slow...

Comment: You need to keep your image data in memory - especially when you are trying to create a paint like program. Believe me - my code above is much faster than any `fseek`...

Comment: But after all I still have to write it to the stream.

Comment: @Lively - well - you have to write to file when you are done. Does this "stream" represent the interface to the graphics card, on your system?

Comment: On the way it is not..it saves any edit in real time. I will do my best to not brake the mechanism.

Comment: I have made some "untested" changes to my code to guide you with implementing this in your environment. UNTESTED. Use with care; do proper initialization; add error checking; etc.

Comment: Allrights thank you. I can not use `printf()` just saying. It is not included because there is no use of it in the engine.

Comment: It is there for testing the basic algorithm. Just take it out. A paint like program on a platform that doesn't support `printf`. You are going to have a really hard time getting something to work - how do you plan to debug?

Comment: I wont.. and there is no compiller debug even. Im not aiming to make photoshop or something. Just a simple paint-like program. It is in game dev engine so its kinda precious.

Comment: Recommendation: get it working on a real computer, then port it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). There are extensions to it that handle anti-aliasing too.

Comment: Oh yes i know that algorithm. But it is originally writen for a rhombus figure right. I will try to implement it to the environment of mine.